# HTML template design view error

Tags: html, css

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13568693/collapsed-wesite-template-when-i-mininize-the-browser. Sorry for my previous meaningless question.

I have a HTML website template with 100% width. The webpage is showed correctly in full browser window. But i change the size of the browser window  means the entire design collapsed. I think the fault is in css html and body tag. can any one fix this error.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    <title>title</title>

    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/layout.css" type="text/css" media="screen" />

</head>


<body>

    <header id="header">
        <hgroup>
            <h1 class="site_title"><a href="index.html">Admin</a></h1>
            <h2 class="section_title">Dashboard</h2><div class="btn_view_site"><a href="">View </a></div>
        </hgroup>
    </header> <!-- end of header bar -->

    <section id="secondary_bar">
        <div class="user">
            <p>John Doe (<a href="#">3 Messages</a>)</p>
            <!-- <a class="logout_user" href="#" title="Logout">Logout</a> -->
        </div>
        <div class="breadcrumbs_container">
            <article class="breadcrumbs"><a href="index.html">Admin</a> <div class="breadcrumb_divider"></div> <a class="current"></a></article>
        </div>
    </section><!-- end of secondary bar -->
```

css :

```
html, div, map, dt, isindex, form, header, aside, section, section, article, footer {  
    display: block;  
} 

html, body {
height: 100%;
margin: 0;
padding: 0;
font-family: "Helvetica Neue", Helvetica, Arial, Verdana, sans-serif;
background: #F8F8F8;
font-size: 12px;
}

.clear {
clear: both;
}
```

Comment: Please paste the HTML and CSS that you currently have into your question.

Comment: I sent my partial HTML and CSS code..

Comment: Thanks, that is helpful. Could you also point out what part of it is not behaving like you intended? A screenshot or just a more detailed description would help.

Comment: Also, I don't see anything that sets a width of 100%, contrary to your initial description.

Comment: Am also try to put width:100% but no use..

Comment: why are you setting all tag display property as block don't do this try appying this css to individual tag

Answer (score 0):

I'm still not sure exactly what you want. However, if you don't want the width of the page to resize then you need to use a size unit that will not change with the width of the window, such as px or em, for example:

```
width: 1000px;
```